# Workbook.close not working

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to do a save and close macro.

It is a workbook containing macro (xlsm), which I'm removing the macro and saving it into 2 other different path as xlsx. I want the workbook to close afterward, but it is not working.

Outcome:
1 xlsm, 2 xlsx, closed after save.

```
Sub saveas()

*saves the workbook before removing macro
ThisWorkbook.Save

ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 1")).Select
Selection.Delete

Worksheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Copy
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.saveas Filename:="path1\list.xlsx"
ActiveWorkbook.saveas Filename:="path2\list.xlsx"

ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False


End Sub
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working now.
Needed to close the copy workbooks and the current workbook, I was missing another close line.

```
Sub saveas()

*saves the workbook before removing marco
ThisWorkbook.Save

ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 1")).Select
Selection.Delete

Worksheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Copy
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.saveas Filename:="path1\list.xlsx"
ActiveWorkbook.saveas Filename:="path2\list.xlsx"
ActiveWorkbook.Close

ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False


End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the

```
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

To

```
ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Activeworkbook refers to any Activeworkbook but Thisworkbook targets the workbook on which the code resides.